# Combine parts of an array in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, arrays

Is there a fast way to get all the items of an array that have even indexes and put them into a new array in VB.NET?

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I see questions like this, and answers that use LINQ I always want to know how big, and how often.  How big is the array and how often the code will be used.  If this is something that will be used often LINQ isn't the answer.

Here is a test with a comparison of LINQ and an alternative

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Debug.WriteLine("")
    prng.NextBytes(oldArray)
    useLinq()
    useOther()
End Sub

Dim prng As New Random
Dim oldArray(131072) As Byte
Dim stpw As New Stopwatch

Private Sub useLinq()
    stpw.Restart()
    Dim newArray() As Byte = Enumerable.Range(0, oldArray.Length).Where(Function(i) i Mod 2 = 0).Select(Function(i) oldArray(i)).ToArray()
    stpw.Stop()
    Debug.WriteLine("{0} {1:n0} {2:n0} {3} {4} {5}", "L", stpw.ElapsedMilliseconds, newArray.Length, newArray(0), newArray(1), newArray(newArray.Length - 1))
End Sub

Private Sub useOther()
    stpw.Restart()
    Dim foo As New List(Of Byte)
    For x As Integer = 0 To oldArray.Length - 1 Step 2
        foo.Add(oldArray(x))
    Next
    Dim newArray() As Byte = foo.ToArray
    stpw.Stop()
    Debug.WriteLine("{0} {1:n0} {2:n0} {3} {4} {5}", "O", stpw.ElapsedMilliseconds, newArray.Length, newArray(0), newArray(1), newArray(newArray.Length - 1))
End Sub
```

Comment: OK, care to share where the bug is.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is to do it with a for-loop but you could do something like this with linq.

```
Dim newArray = Enumerable.Range(0, oldArray.Length) _
                         .Where(Function(i) i Mod 2 = 0) _
                         .Select(Function(i) oldArray(i)) _
                         .ToArray()
```

EDIT: 
    here's an example with byte array

```
Dim oldArray As Byte() = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
Dim newArray As Byte() = Enumerable.Range(0, oldArray.Length).Where(Function(i) i Mod 2 = 0).Select(Function(i) oldArray(i)).ToArray()
```

Comment: I have an array of bytes and it says that they dont have the same signature! I dont understand it very well.

Comment: Unfortunatelly: Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Where' can be called with these arguments:
    Extension method 'Public Function Where(predicate As System.Func(Of Integer, Integer, Boolean)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Integer)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Nested function does not have the same signature as delegate 'System.Func(Of Integer, Integer, Boolean)'.

Comment: and this: Extension method 'Public Function Where(predicate As System.Func(Of Integer, Boolean)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Integer)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Lambda parameter 'i' hides a variable in an enclosing block, a previously defined range variable, or an implicitly declared variable in a query expression.